# Выложить на маркет приложение

Tags: android

Доброго времени суток! уже почти закончил писать приложение, осталось допилить пару косяков. хочу выложить его на маркет и сделать бесплатным. Не знаю как быть с русским языком, отдельно сделать прогу на русском, отдельно на английском, либо создать папочку с русскими стрингами для локализации. Может кто даст пару советов по поводу маркета, по поводу совместимостей, у кого какие были подводные камни. может ньюансы какие-то. спасибо.

Comment: покажи прогу =)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Добрый день!

Нет необходимости делать разные версии приложения только из за локализации. В Android это уже все предусмотрено на уровне ресурсов.  В вашем проекте есть директория res, а в ней есть

```
values\strings.xml
```

Для других языковых версий вам нужно всего лишь создать директории

```
values-en\
values-fr\
и.т.д.
```

Удачи!

Comment: это я понимаю прекрасно. Уже давно создал папку для русского.  Но есть проблема. Допустим русские купят телефон где-то в англии и у них будет локализация английская, но они захотят на русском. Можно поменять локализацию в настройках телефона, но вдруг есть пользователи которые не знают как это сделать. во-вторых, русская локализация сработает ли она для Белоруссии,Украины, и других русскоязычных стран? Мне нужно сделать так чтоб в русских странах было на русском, а в остальных на английском

Comment: Локализация не работает для конкретной страны. она работает для языка установленного устройства.  Если в Белоруссии установлен русский язык, то ваш апп будет на русском и.т.д. Если вам нужно чтоб в других странах он был на английсокм то локализацию по умолчанию делайте на английском. Т.е. values\strings.xml английский язык, а русский язык в values-ru\

Comment: >> Допустим русские купят телефон где-то в англии и у них будет локализация английская, но они захотят на русском.

захотят - переключат локаль на русский.

Comment: В таком случае, вам только внутри приложения делать настройки и в зависимости от выбранного в настройках языка включать нужную локализацию. Но а по умолчанию сделать так как я написал выше.

Локаль программно переключается так:
    Resources res = context.getResources();
    DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
    android.content.res.Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
    conf.locale = new Locale(language_code.toLowerCase());
    res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);

Comment: зачем всю локаль переключать программно? надо сделать настройку переключения стрингов в аппе, а не во всем девайсе

Comment: все-равно придется в коде узнавать локаль потому, что у меня база данных состоит из английских и из русских полей, поэтому в зависимости от локализации будет выборка разная, но я думаю это не проблема, это я сделаю. А что насчет названия приложения? как оно будет выглядеть на маркете, оно будет на английском всегда или тоже будет по локализации меняться?

Comment: имя приложения прописывается в ресурсах, так что никаких проблем. Оно будет корректно подставлено по текущей локали.

Comment: Название в маркете должно меняться в зависимости от локализации маркета. Он это берет из ресурсов вашего апа, заливаемого.

Comment: спасибо. буду делать все-таки одно приложение

Answer (score 2):

Конечно делать разные языковые ресурсы, а дальше уже пусть в зависимости от локали пользователя язык меняется сам, оставьте эту работу системе